# SuiteCRM different dashboard for each user roles or groups

Tags: php, sugarcrm, suitecrm

I'm new to **suiteCRM** my question is how can I make different *dash board* accordion to user *roles* or *groups*?

Ex:- All managers see over roll details of company in the dash board. but sales man dash board only their sales details etc..

I would appreciate if anyone can help me? thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the solution from SuiteCRM [forum](https://suitecrm.com/forum/suitecrm-7-0-discussion/827-dashlet-security-opportunity-by-month).

1. create a role (say) *Default role*
2. Create a new group (say) *Default group*
3. assigned to it with no rights for anything (all columns are red)
4. go to **Security Suite Setting** and unchecked **New User Group Popup**
5. then select *Default group* from drop down menu and select *all* from modules drop down menu and click add button (these are show under Default Groups for New Records section - see attached image )
6. then you can add roles and groups to user as you want.
   [image]

> Note: with this method when you created a new user he can't access any
>   module with default